# printing quick report from sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures, delphi-7

i am trying to print specifics detail for a specific record from a database by the following code

```
procedure TReportsForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edit1.Text = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter the serial number first');
    Edit1.SetFocus;
  end
  else
  begin
    with AddIndividualsAccountADOQuery do
    begin
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('Select * from IndividualAccount where [Serial Number]=:Sno');
      Parameters.ParamByName('Sno').Value:=edit1.Text;
      Open;
      Active := True;
      singlememberreportform.QuickRep1.Preview;
    end;

    if AddIndividualsAccountADOQuery.RecordCount = 0 then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Empty Jonathan database to view records.');
    end
  end;
end;
```

the problem is that when i run the program, the quickreport displays all the records in the database instead of printing only records with edit1.text.in other words the report that runs is similar to just typing

```
procedure TReportsForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  singlememberreportform.QuickRep1.Preview;
end;
```

Any idea of the problem?

Comment: singlememberreportform.QuickRep1 is surely using ReportsForm.AddIndividualsAccountADOQuery, not an other dataset?

Comment: Also, setting Active to True after the call to Open is superfluous!